# Is there a method to get Graphical output (MatPlot, Gym render) in/from Docker ? (WSL2 Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, wsl2

I am running a ML project in Docker.  The calcalculations works smoothly but I need graphics to study the progress!
I am running Docker in WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04 om my PC.

The architecture:

1. Windows 11 (Pro)
2. Runing WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04
3. Start Docker and run Python script in Docker

I get graphical output in my WSL2  Ubuntu environement. Xeyes, Matplot and OpenAi gym render are all working when testing on WSL 2 Ubuntu,  The setting  "export DISPLAY=:0" is used.
But when I start my Docker, and test the same programs inside docker nothing happens. (No testing of xeyes in Docker, not installed)

I have no clue! Is there a method to get Matplot and "OpenAI gym render" working in Docker?

**Thes code:**
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()

**OpenAI gym:**
import gym
print('gym:', gym.**version**)
envs = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="human")
envs.reset()
envs.render()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.